# Need to convert excel IF AND statement into VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have a long IF AND statement in excel (exceeding the limit) that i need to convert into VBA but cant get it to work.

I have two columns of text lists (C & D) that I want to determine the resulting risk level in column E.

the IF AND statement that i came up with is this for a single cell:

```
=IF(AND(C2="Improbable",D2="Acceptable"),"Low",IF(AND(C2="Improbable",D2="Tolerable"),"Medium",IF(AND(C2="Improbable",D2="Unacceptable"),"High",IF(AND(C2="Improbable",D2="Undesirable"),"Medium",IF(AND(C2="Possible",D2="Acceptable"),"Low",IF(AND(C2="Possible",D2="Tolerable"),"Medium",IF(AND(C2="Possible",D2="Unacceptable"),"Critical",IF(AND(C2="Possible",D2="Undesirable"),"High",IF(AND(C2="Probable",D2="Acceptable"),"Medium",IF(AND(C2="Probable",D2="Tolerable"),"HIgh",IF(AND(C2="Probable",D2="Unacceptable"),"Critical",IF(AND(C2="Possible",D2="Undesirable"),"High",""))))))))))))
```

and this works but there are too many IF statements for excel.

Any advice on how to convert this to VBA and for the entire column?

Comment: Have you tried to write any code yourself ?

Comment: Hi, yes i tried this: Sub RiskLevel()

    
If Likelihood = "Improbable" And Severity = "Unacceptable" Then
     RiskLevel = "High"
    
ElseIf Likelihood = "Improbable" And Severity = "Acceptable" Then
    RiskLevel = "Low"
    
ElseIf Likelihood = "Improbable" And Severity = "Tolerable" Then
     RiskLevel = "Medium"
    

End If


End Sub

Comment: but it didnt seem to work

Comment: i also tried the record macro function and it didnt work either :(

Comment: On another note, you have a duplicate Statement: `IF(AND(C2="Possible",D2="Undesirable"),"High"`

Comment: thanks - i must have missed that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a user defined function

```
Public Function ReturnRiskLevel(c as range,d as range) as string


Select case c
      case ="Improbable"
           select case D
              case ="Acceptable" 
                  ReturnRiskLevel = "Low"
               case ="Tolerable" , "Undesirable"
                   ReturnRiskLevel = "Medium"
               case ="Unacceptable" 
                    ReturnRiskLevel ="High"


             end select
    case = "Possible"
           select case D
              case ="Acceptable" 
                  ReturnRiskLevel = "Low"
               case ="Tolerable" 
                   ReturnRiskLevel = "Medium"
               case ="Unacceptable"
                   ReturnRiskLevel = "Critical",
               case = "Undesirable"
                    ReturnRiskLevel ="High"
           end select
           'etc
     end select
   end function
```

you then use it in the spreadsheet  as =ReturnRiskLevel(c2,d2) and then copy down

Answer (score 0):

My way to go would be to use multiplicative values (at least that's how I had to learn FMEA). You give each level a value, multiply them and then you should get the desired outcome. Below is an example, you may have to tweak the values a bit, but there should be examples in your Textbooks etc.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getSeverityLevel(ByVal mode As String, ByVal effect As String) as String
    Dim modeVal As Long
    Dim effectVal As Long
    Dim riskVal As Long

    Select Case mode
        Case "Improbable":  modeVal = 1
        Case "Possible":    modeVal = 2
        Case "Probable":    modeVal = 3
    End Select

    Select Case effect
        Case "Acceptable":  effectVal = 1
        Case "Tolerable":   effectVal = 2
        Case "Undesirable": effectVal = 4
        Case "Unacceptable": effectVal = 8
    End Select

    riskVal = modeVal * effectVal
    Select Case riskVal
        Case 1
            getSeverityLevel = "Low"
        Case 2 To 5
            getSeverityLevel = "Medium"
        Case 6 To 11
            getSeverityLevel = "High"
        Case 12 To 24
            getSeverityLevel = "Critical"
        Case Else
            getSeverityLevel = "Undefined"    
    End Select

End Function
```

Yields:
[image]

The Field with the Low, Medium etc. contain the code `=getSeverityLevel($A2;B$1)` etc. You can plug in any two fields into the funciton. If there is an invalid value used to call the function it should return "Undefined".